# Devexpress. Какой элемент используется для редактирования текста?

Tags: c#, devexpress

**Используется**

- Visual Studio 2015
- Devexpress 15.1

Планируется на WinForm разместить элемент для редактирования текста.
В качестве редактирования предполагается использовать следующие функции:

1. возможность вставки картинок из буфера обмена;
2. заливка текста выбранным цветом;
3. смена цвета шрифта текста; смена толщины шрифта;
4. подсветка синтаксиса различных языков программирования;

Дополнительное требование: возможность форматирование текста с помощью "горячих" клавиш.

**Вопрос:**
В каком элементе Devexpress можно выполнять все либо частичные вышеописанные функции?

Comment: какой-нибудь richtextbox

Comment: @ Grundy Такой или может что-то ещё есть?  [ссылка](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/5807/Controls-and-Libraries/Rich-Text-Editor/Getting-Started/How-to-Create-a-Simple-Word-Processor-with-a-Bar-UI)

Comment: Посмотрите на [ссылка](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/6975/Controls-and-Libraries/Rich-Text-Editor/Fundamentals/RichEditControl)

Comment: @KamikyIT У меня в toolbox чего-то таких элементов нет... Не подскажите как их можно подключить?

Comment: @koverflow это DevExpress'овский контролл. Можете найти в гугле :)

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/

Comment: Вообще говоря - данный вопрос оффтоп для SO, т.к. у devexpress есть собственная поддержка, которой можно и нужно задавать подобные вопросы. Голосую за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: @KamikyIT `это DevExpress овский контролл. Можете найти в гугле` -
 Не могли бы разъяснить? 1. Открываю VS, 2. создаю проект  см. ссылку`http://prntscr.com/g5koc3` 3. В Туле должны находится все необходимые `rich...` см. скрин `http://prntscr.com/g5kqz0`. Или я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: @koverflow https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/ вот это я говорил вам загуглить.

Comment: @koverflow посмотрил ваши скриншоты. вы не добавили devexpress'овские контроллы. для этого необходимо добавить dll библиотки в проект(по умолчанию, при установке devexpress они поставляются и контроллы становятся видны в студии). возможно, вам нужно либо переустановить, либо добавить dll-ки вручную.

Comment: @KamikyIT *1.* `либо добавить dll-ки вручную.` - как это сделать ? разместить в нужной папке или прописать в ссылках проекта? *2.* По присланной вами ссылке. Какие ограничения на триальную версию? **3.** Вот контролы, которые установились http://prntscr.com/g5l7to. Т.е. я так понимаю, что я что-то некорректно установил ? Это не все? **4.** Спасибо за поддержку.. Наверное оформляйте ответ.